# PyQt5 QLine setInputMask + setValidator IP address

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

Problem to combine a setInputMask and setValidator IPv4 Address into a QlineEdit

I have a QLineEdit to set my IPv4 address. 
In the first time, I set my QLineEdit with setInputMask to have " . . . "
In the second time, I'm using a Ip Validator to check if it's a IP address

The problem is when I'm using separately, it's working but together, I can't edit my QLineEdit...

```
self.lineEdit_IP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.lineEdit_IP.setGeometry(120,0,160,30)
self.lineEdit_IP.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
self.lineEdit_IP.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
self.lineEdit_IP.setInputMask("000.000.000.000")
#Set IP Validator
regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){0,3}$')
validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp)
self.lineEdit_IP.setValidator(validator)
```

Comment: Try changing `self.lineEdit_IP.setInputMask ("000.000.000.000")` to `self.lineEdit_IP.setInputMask ("000.000.000.000;0")`

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a mask for QLine changes it's contents from empty to specified symbols. In your case "empty" QLine actually looks like "**...**". That's why regex failed.
You could use your own overridden validator:

```
class IP4Validator(Qt.QValidator):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(IP4Validator, self).__init__(parent)

    def validate(self, address, pos):
        if not address:
            return Qt.QValidator.Acceptable, pos
        octets = address.split(".")
        size = len(octets)
        if size > 4:
            return Qt.QValidator.Invalid, pos
        emptyOctet = False
        for octet in octets:
            if not octet or octet == "___" or octet == "   ": # check for mask symbols
                emptyOctet = True
                continue
            try:
                value = int(str(octet).strip(' _')) # strip mask symbols
            except:
                return Qt.QValidator.Intermediate, pos
            if value < 0 or value > 255:
                return Qt.QValidator.Invalid, pos
        if size < 4 or emptyOctet:
            return Qt.QValidator.Intermediate, pos
        return Qt.QValidator.Acceptable, pos
```

and use it like this

```
    validator = IP4Validator()
    self.ipAddrLineEdit.setValidator(validator)
```

with masks like "**000.000.000.000;_**" or "**000.000.000.000;** " <--with whitespace at the end